# Convert HTML divs to Java/JSON objects?

Tags: java, json, jackson, web-crawler, marshalling

Is there a way where I can read an entire website in HTML in my code and then convert the HTML to java or json objects, kinda? Would be cool to crawl a site and the extract text from certain divs. Is there som way to use a marshaller for this?

Comment: https://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could check `xpath` which can be used to identify html elements on webpages. It can select certain elements or search for texts using regular expressions.

For example this would be the xpath to your questions paragraph `//*[@id="question"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/p` (extracted from chrome dev tools). It can be used in combination with selenium web driver if you want to crawl a webpage using java.